Understanding Goldstein examples of violations of weak and strong Newton 3rd law
Goldstein gives the following two examples for violations of 1) the weak form (force vectors are equal and opposite) of Newton's 3rd Law and 2) of the strong form (force vectors are equal and opposite and act along the vector connecting the particles) only:

If two charges are moving uniformly with parallel velocity vectors that are not perpendicular to the line joining the charges, then the net mutual forces are equal and opposite but do not lie along the vector between the charges. Consider, further, two charges moving (instantaneously) so as to "cross the T," i.e., one charge moving directly at the other, which in turn is moving at right angles to the first. Then the second charge exerts a nonvanishing magnetic force on the first, without experiencing any magnetic reaction force at that instant.

My electromagnetism is fairly rusty so I am not sure I totally follow these examples. My attempts using the (incorrect) heuristic that a particle in motion generates a magnetic field in the same way that a steady current in the same direction would (Biot-Savart law):

Consider particle 1 travelling along the x-axis at velocity $\vec{v}_1 = v \hat x$, $\vec{r}_1 = (vt,y_0,0)$ while particle 2 is also travelling with $\vec{v}_1 = v \hat x$ but which is somewhat above the x-axis and behind particle 1, $\vec{r}_2 = (vt - x_0,y_0,0)$. Then using the Lorentz force law my heuristic suggests that the force of particle 1 on particle 2, $\vec F_{21}$, is in the $+y$ direction while the force of particle 2 on particle 1, $\vec F_{12}$ is in the $-y$ direction (and these forces have equal magnitude too), and indeed these forces are not collinear with $\vec r_2 - \vec r _1$.

Here, are we to imagine that $\vec{r}_1 = (0,vt - y_0,0)$ and $\vec{r}_2 = (vt - x_0,0,0)$ with $x_0<y_0$? Then, at the instant where particle 2 crosses the origin, I think we would have $\vec F_{12}$ in the $+x$ direction but $\vec F_{21} = \vec 0$ because the magnetic field and $\vec v_2$ are collinear.


Is the above a correct understanding of what Goldstein is describing?

For scenario 2, to satisfy the conditions of the setup you want something like $\vec{r}_1=(0, vt, 0)$ and $\vec{r}_2=(vt, y_0, 0)$ with $y_0>0$. That will satisfy (a) particle 1 moving toward particle 2 at $t=0$, and (b) particle 2 moving perpendicular to particle 1 at $t=0$. If you draw it out, you can see your example doesn't do that. You should find the magnetic field due to 2 at 1 is in the $-z$ direction (into the page), while the magnetic field due to 1 at 2 is zero. This is easy to see from the Biot-Savart law, $\vec{B} \propto d \vec{\ell} \times \vec{r}$, but $d\vec{\ell} || \vec{r}$.

Ah, thank you! I had missed a few things, including that $\vec F_{21}$ is $\vec 0$ because the magnetic field there is zero, not because $\vec v_2 || \vec B$ there. I'd be glad to accept exactly what you've written as an answer by the way, @Andrew.

For scenario 2, to satisfy the conditions of the setup you want something like $\vec{r}_1=(0,v t,0)$ and $\vec{r}_2=(vt,y_0,0)$ with $y_0 > 0$.That will satisfy (a) particle 1 moving toward particle 2 at $t=0$, and (b) particle 2 moving perpendicular to particle 1 at $t=0$. If you draw it out, you can see your example doesn't do that. Assuming particle 2 has positive charge, you should find the magnetic field due to 2 at 1 is in the $-z$ direction (into the page), while the magnetic field due to 1 at 2 is zero. This is easy to see from the Biot-Savart law, which in this case implies $\vec{B}\propto \vec{v}_1 \times \hat{r}_{12}$, where $v_1$ is the velocity of particle 1 and $\hat{r}_{12}$ is a unit vector pointing from 1 to 2, but $\vec{v}_1 || \hat{r}_{12}$.

Diagrammatically the situation is as follows.

The magnetic field $\vec B$ produced by a charge $q$ moving at a velocity $\vec v$ at a position $\vec r$ relative to the charge is $\vec B = \dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\dfrac {q\,\vec v \times \vec r}{r^3}$.
In the left-hand diagram there is no magnetic field produced by charge $q_1$ at position $\vec r_1$ because $\vec v_1$ is parallel to $\vec r_1$, and so charge $q_2$ feels no Lorentz force.
In the right-hand diagram charge $q_2$ does produce a magnetic field $\vec B_2$ at position $\vec r_2$ because $\vec v_2$ is perpendicular to $\vec r_2$, and charge $q_1$ field a Lorentz force to the right due to this magnetic field.
